# esriRequest json response to feature layer

Tags: json, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am using JavaScript 4.7 and I am able to retrieve json using esriRequest from our ArcGIS server.

However, I have difficulty in showing this data on the map layer.

the call `map.addLayer(featureLayer);` is not working. Here is the code I am using

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no" />
    <title>Request Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://js.arcgis.com/4.2/esri/css/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://js.arcgis.com/4.2/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
    <style>
        html,        body,
        #viewDiv {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        body {
            background-color: #FFF;
            overflow: hidden;
            font-family: "Trebuchet MS";
        }
        #header {
            height: 3%;
            overflow: auto;
        }
    </style>

    <script src="http://js.arcgis.com/4.7/"></script>
    <script>

        require([
        "esri/request",
        "dojo/on",
        "esri/Map",
        "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
        "esri/renderers/support/jsonUtils",
      "esri/views/MapView",
      "esri/symbols/SimpleMarkerSymbol",
      "esri/Color", "esri/renderers/SimpleRenderer",
            "esri/tasks/support/FeatureSet",
      "dojo/domReady!"

        ], function (
        esriRequest,
        on,
        Map,
        FeatureLayer,
        rendererJsonUtils, MapView, SimpleMarkerSymbol, Color, SimpleRenderer,  
            FeatureSet
      ) {

            var map = new Map({
                basemap: "streets"
            });

            var view = new MapView({
                container: "viewDiv",
                map: map,
                zoom: 4,
                center: [15, 65] // longitude, latitude
            });
            var input = document.getElementById("inputUrl");

            /************************************************
             *
             * Define the 'options' for our request.
             *
             *************************************************/
            var options = {
                query: {
                    f: 'json'
                } 
                responseType: 'json'
            };

            // Make the request on a button click using the
            // value of the 'input' text.
            on(btnQuery, "click", function () {
                var url = input.value;
                esriRequest(url, options).then(function (response) {
                    var responseJSON = JSON.stringify(response, null, 2);

                    var search_layer_result = JSON.parse(responseJSON);
                    var fs = new FeatureSet(search_layer_result);
                    var layerDefinition = {
                        "displayFieldName": "NAME",
                        "geometryType": "esriGeometryPoint",
                        "spatialReference": {
                            "wkid": 32633
                        },
                        "fields": [
                          {
                              "name": "OBJECTID",
                              "type": "esriFieldTypeOID",
                              "alias": "OBJECTID"
                          },
                          {
                              "name": "NAME",
                              "type": "esriFieldTypeString",
                              "alias": "NAME",
                              "length": 50
                          }
                        ]
                    };
                    var featureCollection = {
                        layerDefinition: layerDefinition,
                        featureSet: fs
                    };
                    var featureLayer = new FeatureLayer(featureCollection);
                   map.addLayer(featureLayer);

                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div>
            <h2>Using esri/request</h2>
            <button id="btnQuery">Make Request</button>
            <input id="inputUrl" type="text" value="https://arcgisserver/map">
        </div>        
    </div>
    <div id="viewDiv">MAP HERE</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: If you have the URL to the FeatureServer, you can use that to instantiate a FeatureLayer object, e.g. `layer = new FeatureLayer({url: "https://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/USA/MapServer/0"});` Is that what you want? See here for details: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-FeatureLayer.html
Oh, and one minor thing: As far as I know there is no such thing as Java 4.7, do you mean *ArcGIS API for JavaScript 4.7* by any chance?

Comment: One more thing: In version 4.x, the map object does not have a method called `addLayer()`. You should probably be using `add()`: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-Map.html#add

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation :

> FeatureLayers may be created in one of three ways: from a service URL, an ArcGIS portal item ID, or from an array of client-side graphics

So in your case, you would use the third option :
https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-FeatureLayer.html#source

By looking at your layerDefinition, your esriRequest should return two values : OBJECTID and NAME

Now use them to populate the attributes of your graphics :

```
var features = [
  {
    geometry: {
      type: "point",
      x: -100,
      y: 38
    },
    attributes: {
      ObjectID: objectid,
      name: name
    }
  },
  ...
];

var featureLayer = new FeatureLayer({
  source: features
});
```

And as `Berend` said, in ArcGIS Javascript version 4, you should be using :

```
map.add(featureLayer);
```